# Sum the odd positioned and the even positioned integers in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm

What is the most elegant way to sum 'each number on odd position' with 'each number on even position multiplied by 3'? I must obide this prototype

```
int computeCheckSum(const int* d)
```

My first try was to use this but my idea was flawed. I can't find a way to tell which element is even this way.

```
int sum=0;
for_each(d,
         d+11,
         [&sum](const int& i){sum+=(i%2==1)?3*i:i;}
);
```

example

> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 1+2*3+3+4*3+5=27

Comment: `my idea was flawed` Why exactly? I see no problem in the even/odd check

Comment: khm. `i%2==1` means it's odd...

Comment: (i%2==1) checks if my number is even, not its position. I want to multiply it, if its on even position, not if it is even

Comment: Your question is not clear ... are all the odd indexes / even indexes summed into one place (int sum;)  or should your sum also be an array?

Comment: i%2==0 would be an even number.

Comment: So not the value has to be even, but the index?

Comment: The modulo operator ('%') returns the remainder of a division. Why would you expect dividing an even number by 2 to leave a remainder of 1?

Comment: In a plain old for loop: `int sum = 0; for(int index = 0; index < arraylength; index += 2) {sum += 3 * array[i] + array[i+1];}`

Comment: @deviantfan I asked for an ELEGANT solution...possibly using <algorithms> and lambdas

Comment: @Slazer Longer, more complicated code and O(n) completely unnecessary function calls etc. == elegant? well...

Comment: @Slazer: You talk about elegant solutions? People wondering whether you're talking about values or indexes and your example is 1 2 3 4 5? *sigh*

Comment: Obvious *is* elegant. *Clarity* is elegance. Inelegant is unnecessarily complicating an implementation in an attempt to be "clever" or show off your language knowledge. Elegant code is code that, by virtue of picking the perfect set of abstractions, has taken a complicated problem and rendered it simple. This "problem" is already reductively simple, offering no opportunity for anything that could be characterized as "elegance". The best you can do is straightforward/obvious.

Comment: I appologize for the vague question. I have corrected it.

Comment: My contention is not to solve the problem, but rather to learn some C++11 language features by solving it. I found it interesting. If I were to solve it in a prodiction code I would not hesitate to use a simple loop.

Comment: That's fine. Deliberating solving a problem in an obtuse way as a means of learning language features is a great way to learn. Just don't confuse such a solution with elegance.

Comment: How does your function determine how many elements are pointed to by `d`? In your example, you hard code it.

Comment: It is a compile-time constant. Its actually 12, an even number.

Comment: The point is that if you're writing a *function* to do this computation, you don't want to have the number of elements hardcoded .The entire point of a function is that it's a parameterizable bit of reusable computation. You should be able to use it with arrays of arbitrary lengths. That means you want a second parameter for the length. If you can't do that (suggesting this is homework), then the array needs some sort of terminator value that let's you know when you're at the end, and you'll be using a regular `for` loop, not `for_each`.

Comment: Well the point of this all was to avoid the usual function and use lambdas instead. As you see I have no access to the array (its constant) nor can I change the prototype.

Comment: *Why* can't you change the prototype? Is this an assignment? If you created it for yourself, you screwed up the prototype. An array is converted into a point when passed as an argument, so there's no way for the function to determine the number of elements pointed to by `d`. Hardcoding that into the function is nonsensical. If you *didn't* create this prototype (i.e. your teacher did), then there must be some terminator value you're expected to look for.

Comment: Why does it need to be elegant?  What's wrong a fundamental `for` loop?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Nothing is wrong with a for loop. I just want to explore some other solutions.

Comment: How does one determine the capacity or size of the array?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Its fixed at compile time. It is always even.

Comment: @"Its actually 12, an even number."   Then the second parameter you're passing to `for_each` is wrong.  The `last` parameter is supposed to be one *past* the last valid element in the sequence. That would be `d + 12`.

Comment: I love it.  Even.  There is an infinite quantity of even numbers.  With any given loop, it should have a termination criteria.  Tell your customers that the prototype is flawed and should have two more parameters:  capacity and size (quantity to sum).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Its 12. And it will never ever be anything different. I can guarantee!

Comment: @Mud Thanks for the notification. I agree, it should be d+12.

Comment: Your prototype is still broken, an objectively terrible function design. Hardcoding numbers *in general* is bad, but taking a function that can trivially work on arrays of any length hardcoding it to only work on exactly 12 items is just nuts. It adds nothing to this exercise.

Comment: @Mud To defend (kind of) this (terrible) design, I must say the array is a private class attribute.

Comment: @OP: Are you trying to calculate a UPC barcode number's [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit#UPC)?

Comment: @NayukiMinase actually, I am counting the EAN13 linear barcode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you change the number of elements in that private element, this distant code breaks in a way the compiler can't catch. That's bad. If you really only ever want this function to operate on that one, specific array, then don't pass the array in as a parameter. Access it directly. You still don't want to hardcode the number of elements in the algorithm. Assuming the private member is an array of int (rather than pointer to int), you can calculate the number of elements. At the very least, you hardcode that into a constant which leaves near the array declaration.

Comment: @Mus there is a difference between a pointer on array passed as a parameter and a pointer used at the spot? Actually I remember I cant use sizeof(p)/sizeof(*p) in a function when int* p is passed as an argument. That might be what you are talking about

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. So either don't pass the array in as a parameter (access the field directly, and either calculate the count based on that field if it's an array or access the count field directly, too) or also pass in a count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't find a way to tell which element is even this way.

If you insist on using `for_each` (there's no reason to do that here), then you track the index separately:

```
int computeCheckSum(const int* d, int count)
{
    int sum=0;
    int pos=1;
    std::for_each(d, d+count,
             [&sum,&pos](const int& value) { sum += pos++ % 2 ? value : value * 3; } );
    return sum;
}
```

Note I added a `count` parameter, so the function can work on arrays of any length. If you're feeling really perverse, you can remove that parameter and go back to hardcoding the length so the function only works arrays with 12 elements. But if you hope to be good at this some day, doing that should make you feel gross.

Answer (score 1):

These things rarely become very "elegant" in C++ (it seems C++ is asymptotically approaching Perl on the "line noise" index) but since `accumulate` is a left fold, you can pass the index "along the fold":

```
int sum = std::accumulate(d, 
                          d + 11,
                          std::make_pair(0,0), // (index, result)
                          [](std::pair<int, int> r, int x) { 
                               r.second += r.first % 2 ? x : 3 * x; 
                               r.first++; 
                               return r; 
                          }).second;
```

Comment: Sorry, buy I get an incorrect output. For example "int d[]={2,3,4,5}; int sum = std::accumulate(d,d + 4, ..." gives me 26 but it should be 2+9+4+15=30

Comment: I found out where the problem is. The initial element should have been "std::make_pair(0,*d)" and it should iterate from d+1 not from d.

Comment: Oh, you're using the ordinal number ("1,2,3,...") as the position, not the index. Then you should start from `(1,0)`. (Your fix doesn't handle an empty collection.)

Answer (score 0):

You were right. As Mud said, it was just a terrible function design. This is what I needed.

```
int computeCheckSum(){

    int sum = 0;
    bool multiplyBy3 = false;

    for (auto i : m_digits){
        sum += multiplyBy3 ? 3*i : i;
        multiplyBy3 = !multiplyBy3;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Mud's solution is correct using my flawed design. A simple for loop would probably be even a better solution, as everyone said.